# Highmaps labels show in incorrect position

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I've created a simple map with basic configurations. Labels are showing in the incorrect position. Any idea?

```js
var map_chart;

function init_map(){
 
    map_chart =  new Highcharts.chart({
  
        chart: {
            type: 'map',
     renderTo: 'map_container'
        },

        series: [{
            mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        }]
    });

}

$( document ).ready(function() {
 
 init_map();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>

<div id="map_container">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to be caused by how the highmaps object is initiated.

replacing

`map_chart =  new Highcharts.chart({`

with

`map_chart =  new Highcharts.Map({`

solves the problem, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MicheleC/ez13oLaq/4/)

Answer (score -1):

For proper way of creating maps using [Map collection](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/map-collection)

From highmaps docs

> In the map collection reference, each map name is followed by a link to an example. View the source of this example to get started. In short, the GeoJSON version of the map is loaded in a script tag in the page. This GeoJSON object is then registered to the Highcharts.maps object, and applied to the mapData option in the chart setup.
>
> 1. Add the map as a JavaScript element:
>
> `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js">`
>   You can alternatively link to a specific version or subversion of the map at http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/1.1/custom/world.js.
>
> 2. Load it in series.mapData:
>
> mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
>   Alternatively, you can set the default map for all series with the chart.map option:
>
> map: 'custom/world'
>
> 3. Join your data with the map. By default Highmaps is set up to map your data against the hc-keyproperty of the map collection, allowing you to define your data like this:
>
> data: [['us-ny', 0], ['us-mi', 5], ['us-tx', 3], ['us-ak', 5]]
>   For other data joining options, see the series.joinBy and series.keys options.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/ntx8qz95/) demo link

Comment: Instead of copying and pasting from highcharts.com can you please explain which part of my code is incorrect and how to fix?

Besides, The three steps you pasted above, are all followed in my script

Comment: you can see through fiddle link what mistakes you did. I simply go through the doc and did the post. and thanks for down voting **thumps Up :-)**

Comment: I also did go through the docs, which is expected before asking a question. An answer should have more than references to documentation and/or link to fiddles

Comment: fiddle is at the bottom of answer

Comment: I saw the fiddle, and? As I said, an answer shoudl have MORE than a fiddle.

Comment: doc explanation + fiddle  is what i can give as answer

Comment: Ok I see that. I never said you should delete it. I only said that you should improve your answer, mainly because both the docs and fiddle are already available in the Highchart website. Anyway, the combination of your references + my answer should be enough for future people with the same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136624/discussion-between-deep-3015-and-michele).

Comment: Or maybe you can try to enjoy the weekend :-) I think I repeated my point 3+ times. Thanks for the answer